# Qt QCompleter with multiple indexing

Tags: python

For normal Qcompleter, each item in the list has only one index(the name). What I want is for items with multiple indexes to work in a QCompleter.
For example, for a security listed in the financial market, it may has a unique numeric code, such as '00234', and it may also has a tick code for abbreviation, such as 'DFKS'. What I want to do is to complete this item in a QCompleter either by entering the numeric code, or by entering the tick code.
I call it QCompleter with double(or maybe more)indexing.

So how should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Why is this a hard problem? Upon getting a completion of 00234, map it to DFKS, or vice versa. The completer is doing the heavy lifting. All you have to do is map from one namespace to another, based on exact match.